# When did the conjunction "for" become old-fashioned?

Tags: conjunctions, formality

> I am not going to school today, for I am sick.

When did "for" become old-fashioned? Is it still used in everyday conversation?

Comment: The preposition *for* has not yet become old-fashioned. *For* in the sense of 'because' is a conjunction, and it is overly formal/literary.

Comment: I think *for* in the sense of *because* is indeed old-fashioned, and that this is the reason that it is perceived as overly formal. [See this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+I+am+old%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cfor+I+am+old%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20I%20am%20old%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20I%20am%20old%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) for some idea of when it declined in usage. It seems to have peaked in 1880, and has been declining since.

Answer (score 1):

[1942.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20I,%20because%20I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,for%20I;,c0;.t1;,because%20I;,c0)

No, it is no longer used in everday conversation ;)

Comment: This answer is mostly jest.

Comment: No, it's before that. It's so since [1910](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+he%2Cbecause+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecause%20he%3B%2Cc0). ;-)

Comment: 1912 for *he*, 1915 for *she*. 1916 for [all three combined](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+he%2Bfor+she%2Bfor+I%2C+because+he%2Bbecause+she%2Bbecause+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28for%20he%20%2B%20for%20she%20%2B%20for%20I%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28because%20he%20%2B%20because%20she%20%2B%20because%20I%29%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: None of these can qualify as anything more than 'opinion', certainly not a canonical answer.

Comment: One cannot be too sure with these figures: https://www.google.com/#q=%22for+he%22+%22for+she%22+%22for+i%22&tbs=qdr:y (This comment is not a continuation of or related to the previous.)